# How to compare datetime.now with a certain date?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Let's say i have a variable of datetime type; varA = '2016-06-10 12:28:36.697'. What is the best way and how i can compare it with `datetime.now` to make sure the date is the same regardless of the year?

Comment: what have u tried so far??

Comment: Compare the `Month` and `Day`.

Comment: Month, day and time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear if you want to include the time part of the DateTime as well, or simply the Day and Month. Uncomment/tweak for your use:

```
bool AreEqual(DateTime left, DateTime right)
{   
    return left.Day == right.Day && left.Month == right.Month
        // && left.TimeOfDay.Equals(right.TimeOfDay)
    ;
}
```